# Как правильно установить класс?

Tags: html, css

Нужно применить класс, чтобы только к одному div относился следующий код

```
<style>
    div {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        padding: 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
        -moz-border-radius: 2px;
        border-radius: 2px;
        background: #eeece0;
    }
</style>

<div>
    <p>qweqwe text qweqwe text qweqwe test1 qweqwe text qweqwe text qweqwe test2
        qweqwe text qweqwe text qweqwe test3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Дело в том что у меня все div`ы в эти блоки помещаются

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант номер раз: задать слектор от "родителя" к непосредственному потомку - [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/ZpbXm/). Даже если нет родителя, как такового, то в его качестве можно использовать **body**

```
<style>
#parent > div {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: #eeece0;
}
</style>
<div id="parent">
    <div>
    <p>
    qweqwe text qweqwe text qweqwe test1
    qweqwe text qweqwe text qweqwe test2
    qweqwe text qweqwe text qweqwe test3
    </p>
        <div>INNER DIV</div>
        <div>INNER DIV</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Вариант номер два: для этого дива задать или класс, или ID

Comment: Спасиьо!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Как то так.

```
<style>
       .container {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        padding: 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
        -moz-border-radius: 2px;
        border-radius: 2px;
        background: #eeece0;
       }
      </style>

    <div class="container">
    <p>
    qweqwe text qweqwe text qweqwe test1
    qweqwe text qweqwe text qweqwe test2
    qweqwe text qweqwe text qweqwe test3
    </p>
    </div>
```